# Strange lag in PS4 Fifa 20

Tags: ps4, fifa-20

I have normal PS4 and Fifa 20.
I play online every day 2-3 matches 99% with Liverpool.

**Problem:**

Some days (today is also that day) I see slowness in player, the are slower, their response to pass ball is slower.

For example instead of one touch of ball before shooting they made 2 and I get lost ball of course.

Every player is playing like they are stupid
Passing the ball, shooting, moving.
If I move with player (with ball) in normal speed and I try to stop, he is stopping for some time, like they are all sick and without strength.

After I login into game and before match I can see that 80% of players are in excellent form so that is not problem.
I know when there is internet connection problem because then is blocking, now is not blocking, just player are lazy.
I have two internet providers, tried in short time with both of them and no change there.

Controller settings are all on assisted.

Only thing what I think it could be is that players are tired but then I would see that on every player in color bar how I always do on the end of the match.

Friend played against me in friendly online also with Liverpool and he did not have that problem.

Do you have any idea what could be?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds familiar to me. I have lost many games because of disconnection, and something that worked for me:

Never play using wifi, instead you should play using ethernet cable.

Comment: great advice, tnx

Answer (score 0):

Can also go into your xbox network settings and do a test there to see the rating for your NAT.  if it shows up as strict, you might get more issues like this.  Ya want it to be Open or Moderate.